# ArcMap 10.5 Text Boxes Alignment

Tags: arcgis-desktop, text

I am running a script in ArcMap that will update a text box. Some of the text that I am updating it with wraps to two lines, while others are on a single line. What I want to happen is that regardless of the new text being a single or double line, is that the text is left-center adjusted in the box at all times. Currently, it looks like it's left-upper adjusted.

The text box was created from the drawing tool bar as a rectangle text box. I've tried playing around with the Size and Position tab of the box properties window by changing the anchor point, but it doesn't change it when the new text is a single line versus double.

Comment: Have you tried using a text box added via the Insert menu > Text or via the Draw toolbar > Text icon > Text? The different text boxes behave differently when the length/size of the text content changes.

Comment: The issue I've found with the straight text box in Arc is that you can't change its size. The other thing is I need it to wrap, so the rectangle text box seems like the best fit.

Comment: The only wrapping, size-adjusting text feature I've found in the software is the Advanced text/Balloon or other callout symbology. But this seems only to work when used for labeling in 10.4. When I tried using it for inserted text, the size adjusted, but it did not wrap and I could not set the size of the box's height. So if you can fake some points and label them, that might work.